# C#: Create Ints in a loop with names from a table array

Tags: c#

Alright, so I was trying to do a part of my program which just tallies all the numbers in a number (i'm good at translating polish mathematical arguments to english) and I wanted to implement a loop in which new variables are created, and those variables have names from a table array.
Here's the snippet of my code:

```
Random rand = new Random();
        int[] a = { rand.Next(100,999), rand.Next(100, 999), rand.Next(100, 999), rand.Next(100, 999) };    // random numbers
        int j = -1;
        string[] inty = { "k", "l", "m", "n" };    // the array from which i want to extract variable names
        for (int i = 0;i<=a.Length;i++)    // loop
        {
            j++;
            int inty[j] = new int();     // create a new int, where the name of the int is some letter from that array
            Console.WriteLine(a[j]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

So that int that's supposed to be created in the loop should have a name from the next letters in that string array (inty). Does anyone have an idea on how to do this (or replace the code in another way)?

Sincerely,
some random dude on the internet.

Comment: There are more items in `a` than in `inty`, such that even if things worked like this (they don't!) you'd end up with an index out of range exception when there's no variable name left for the last item in `a`.

Comment: right, that was an overlook of me, because i also meant to include "n".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Dictionary for this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] a = { rand.Next(100,999), rand.Next(100, 999), rand.Next(100, 999), rand.Next(100, 999) };    // random numbers
string[] inty = { "k", "l", "m", "n" };    
var variables = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = 0; i<a.Length; i++)
{
    variables.Add(inty[i], a[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(variables[inty[i]]);
}
//example using a variable
Console.WriteLine($"k: {variables["k"]}");
Console.ReadKey();
```

or:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] a = { rand.Next(100,999), rand.Next(100, 999), rand.Next(100, 999), rand.Next(100, 999) };    // random numbers
string[] inty = { "k", "l", "m", "n" };   
var variables = new Dictionary<string, int>(); 
foreach (var item in a.Zip(inty, (i, n) => (i, n)))
{
    variables.Add(item.i, item.n);
}
//example using a variable
Console.WriteLine($"k: {variables["k"]}");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Remember C# is strongly-typed. Variables *must* be declared to the compiler. If you want an identifier to be available as a variable in the IDE, it must be declared that way. Otherwise, you just use the name as *data* held in some other type.

Comment: thank you, that worked for me perfectly and i see i need to look a bit depper into those dictionaries and i (see) they could help me in more things.

Comment: Using Dictionaries too much is a sign of being stuck in a dynamic language mentality (php, javascript), and not have properly embraced the use of types.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question... you may use the modulus function and a hashset maybe

```
HashSet<string> names = new HashSet<strings>();

for (int i = 0;i<=a.Length;i++)  
{

 j = j++ % 3; // Will give 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2... or use ranbd.Next(0,4)
 string forName = inty[j]; // Restricted to 0,1,2
 string newName = $"{forName}{a[j]}";
 if (! names.Contains(newName)
 {
  names.Add(newName);
  Console.WriteLine("Name: {newName}");
 }
 else 
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Ups!: {newName} already used!");
 }
}
```